# Как сделать кнопку активной при нажатии в React?

Tags: reactjs, map

Вопрос с подвохом. Все кнопки визуализируются из приходящих данных через функцию .map() т.е. большинство методов мне не подходит.

Пробовал хранить флаг в стейте и менять класс по нему, но тогда класс меняется сразу у всех кнопок, т.к. используем .map().
Как решить проблему?

Comment: Всё что испробовал меняет стиль сразу у всех кнопок, опять же, из-за использования map, т.к. map просто дублирует кнопки и на выходе мы получаем все кнопки одинаковыми по коду.

Comment: добавь код   пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задачу решил таким образом:

В конструкторе класса пишем:

```
  this.state = {
        clname: 'name0'
    }
```

В кнопке пишем условие присвоение класса и онклик:

```
className={(this.state.clname === 'name' + (item.id)) ? style.activeBTN : ' '} 
onClick={(e) => this.onClickBTN(item.id)}
```

и собственно, функция вызываемая при клике по кнопке

```
onClickBTN(id) {
this.setState({clname: 'name' + id})
}
```

Таким образом, изначально активна(выделена) кнопка с id 0 т.к. в стейте изначально задали (`clname: 'name0'`)

По клику кнопки меняем `name0`на name с id кнопки. Например `clname: 'name2'`. Таким образом под условие с классом будет подходить только кнопка с id2.